# I want to make a graphic in python from csv documents,but it can only show one pair numbers, how can i make it complete?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyplot
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import csv
path = r'C:/Users/AK6PRAKT'
dirs = os.listdir(path) 
s = []
for i in dirs:                             
    if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ".csv": 
        f = open(path+"/"+i)
        iter_f = iter(f);
        str = ""
        for line in iter_f: 
              str = str + line
        s.append(str) 
        with open(path+"/"+i,'r') as r:
            lines=r.readlines()
        with open(path+"/"+i,'w') as w:
            for row in lines:
                if 'Date' not in row:
                    w.write(row)
        from collections import defaultdict
        columns = defaultdict(list)
        import csv
        with open(path+"/"+i) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
                    columns[i].append(v)
        print(columns[0],columns[1])
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
pyplot.plot(columns[0],columns[1])
pyplot.show()
```

actually i there are over 40000 csv files in my computer and first of all, i select 2 series of numbers in the specific positions, one is about the time and the other one is about the battery condition, then I want to make a graphic about the 2 series, one as x-axis and one as y-axis.but the result shows only the last pair of the series, but I want to see the complete graphic in python.

Comment: You need to not create a new `columns` dict for each file, which just throws away all the data from previous files.

Comment: but I need to select the data in a specific position, every csv file has only one line number, but i only need two numbers from the whole line in each file. So I write such command...

Comment: Could you provide an MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: as @jasonharper said, just move the `columns = defaultdict(list)` line outside the loop over files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary work…  as far as I can tell, the important bits are just:

```
from glob import glob
import csv

c1 = []
c2 = []

for path in glob('C:/Users/AK6PRAKT/**/*.csv', recursive=True):
  with open(path) as fd:
    rows = csv.reader(fd)
    # ignore header (I presume this is what your "'Date' not in row" is about)
    next(rows)
    for cols in rows:
      c1.append(cols[0])
      c2.append(cols[1])
```

Comment: thanks for your time and anwser, i was inspired by your anwser, and now this graphic shows successfully.

Comment: but i have another question...:( if you have time, could you pls probably see it ???thanks a lot. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291509/typeerror-occours-when-i-tried-to-get-a-graphic-from-csv-file-in-python