# Typeerror occours when I tried to get a graphic from CSV file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graphics

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyplot
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import numpy as np
path = r'C:\Users\AK6PRAKT\Desktop\6daten'
dirs = os.listdir(path) 
s = []
x = []
y = []
names = []
fig = pyplot.figure()
for i in dirs:                             
    if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ".csv": 
        f = open(path+"/"+i)
        iter_f = iter(f);
        str = ""
        for line in iter_f: 
              str = str + line
        s.append(str) 
        with open(path+"/"+i,'r') as r:
            lines=r.readlines()
        with open(path+"/"+i,'w') as w:
            for row in lines:
                if 'Date' not in row:
                    w.write(row)
        columns = defaultdict(list)
        with open(path+"/"+i) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
                    columns[i].append(v)
                    list_temp1 = columns[0]
                    list_temp1 = np.array(list_temp1)
                    list_temp2 = columns[2]
                    list_temp2 = np.array(list_temp2)
            print(list_temp1,list_temp2)
            y.append(float(list_temp2))                                                    
            names.append(list_temp1)
x = range(len(names))
pyplot.ylim((0, 40)) 
my_y_ticks = np.arange(0, 40, 10)
pyplot.plot(x,y, linewidth=2)
pyplot.xticks(x,names,rotation = 90)
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,10))
pyplot.show()
```

This code works very good if there are only several csv files. BUT i want to apply this code in practice, i need to analyse more than 200000 csv file and make a graphic so that I can see the fluctuation of these datas obviously, but when i want to import these magnificent files, the following Error occours:

```
File "C:/Users/AK6PRAKT/headerremover.py", line 44, in <module>

y.append(float(list_temp2))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I really have no idea about solving that, if anyone can help me, thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: I mean that if I import only 10 or 100 files, the result and the graphic show in python, but if i open 10000 files, such error occours, i am so confused about that...

Comment: The problem is that you are using the operation `float` on a list `list_temp2` and trying to convert all the elements in the list to float at once. You can't do that. `float` requires a scalar argument. You need to convert each element of the list to float one at a time. You can use list comprehension like `y = [float(i) for i in list_temp2]`

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks for your suggestion!! I tried it and it seems that the old problem was solved but now comes a new one... it is like :                     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 2357, in safe_first_element
    raise RuntimeError("matplotlib does not support generators "
RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input

Comment: I don't know which line in your code is this error coming from

Comment: @Bazingaa I don't know neither...maybe i need to add more commands about matplotlib? because it seems like some problems while importing matplotlib.

Comment: Ok, it has to do something with the plotting routines because the error is from matplotlib. Can you try replacing `x = range(len(names))` with `x = np.arange(0, len(names))`?

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for your suggestion! yeah...i tried to post the code in the website that you mentioned, but the system said that i can only post something every 40 mins... is there like some relationship between that website and stackoverflow? Cuz I've never posted any codes at that website.

Comment: @Bazingaa Just tried this, but the Error is the same as the one before.

Comment: What line is the error coming from. Read carefully the full error trace and you will find the line from your code

Comment: May I mention that it's not helpful if you post code completely unchanged, which was already optimized by an SO user (https://stackoverflow.com/q/52223419/8300135) ? I think Sam Mason made a good review job and gave you exactly what you wanted to achieve, but structured and with the appropriate tools python offers. If you would have taken care of the proposal and posted here a new version, nobody would waste time for thinking about how you could optimize your program because of things already solved. Are you even sure that the error you post here still comes up if you use the clean code...?

Comment: Perhaps you could just post the structure of your csv-files and if their structure is completely identical or if there can be variations... Then people here would better understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @SpghttCd I am really grateful that you can give me such objective comment. I had no background about computer science before, it's really a little bit hard for me to deal with such many datas at the very beginning. Actually i am now doing Internship in a german company and i started to learn python one week ago. I got an assignment from my mentor, I tried to devid the whole assignment into several steps, and I searched the commands of each of the steps and then combine them together with some revising. So, it may seem that I did a lot of useless work. I am also trying to make my code better.

Comment: It's completely ok to make mistakes or too complicated approaches as a beginner, so certainly you do not have to explain yourself. We're here to help each other. I just wanted to suggest you to please not post code uncorrected again if it was already optimized in another question before. Even if the question here is now about another detail, people who want to help tend to try to help more - and they cannot know that most of the code was already successfully reviewed in a different question a few days before.

Comment: @SpghttCd I was inspires by (stackoverflow.com/q/52223419/8300135) Sam Mason, but I dare not to revise all the code as he wrote, because I am afraid that if I rewrite then I need to understand the code totally from a different perspective. As a beginner, I want to revise some rows based on the codes that I have sofar understood. BTW, I have found the reason why i can't make the graphic, it's because the format of csv file is falsh, you can find the reason here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295418/how-to-solve-the-error-when-i-draw-graphic-in-python-with-using-datas-in-csv-fil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error code results from an attempt to cast a numpy array to float, which has length > 1:

*Example:*

```
float(np.array([3,2,1]))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-e396216bb2ea>", line 1, in <module>
    float(np.array([3,2,1]))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

*but:*

```
float(np.array([3]))
: 3.0
```

So this error occurs in your line (44, to cite the error message)

```
y.append(float(list_temp2))
```

in case of `list_temp2` has more than one entry. So it should have nothing to do with how many files you process.

*However:*

Like Georgy already mentioned - let's say your code is a little more complicated than the task requires.
Here just a few thoughts of mine...

1. if you need a list of all `csv`-files in a directory, did you have alook at python's `glob`-module? It's capable of searching subdirectories, too...
2. You iterate over a file for reading, again for writing without lines which contain "Date" and then again you read it it again...? That's too much, IIUC. Couldn't you just use the last loop and put your list_temp-stuff there in a conditional, which tests for "contains 'Date'"?
3. Why do you `fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,10))` right before `plt.show()` at the end? This should lead to an unused empty figure.
4. `headerremover.py` combined with your loop and `if 'Date' not in row` looks like if there are many header lines, also in the middle, in your files - is that true? Because if you just would have a header section of n lines at the top of each file, there would be again much simpler ways to skip these lines...