# How to solve the error when i draw graphic in python with using datas in csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I think the problem is the following steps, but just in case，I will also write the whole body of my code down blow. The most strange thing is, this code can read over 6000 csv files and a graphic can also successfully show, but when I want more files to be read, then occours an error. The screenshot shows the graphic and the content of the csv files. as you can see, the path = r'C:\Users\AK6PRAKT\Desktop\6daten' includes all datas and path = r'C:\Users\AK6PRAKT\Desktop\daten' includes only parts of them.enter image description here

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyplot
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import numpy as np
path = r'C:\Users\AK6PRAKT\Desktop\6daten'
dirs = os.listdir(path) 
s = []
x = []
y = []
names = []
...(ignore some steps for reading the datas from csv files)

            print(list_temp1,list_temp2) #list_temp1 is the datas of xaxise, and list_temp2 of yaxise.
            y.append(float(list_temp2))                                                    
            names.append(list_temp1)
x = range(len(names))
pyplot.ylim((0, 40)) 
my_y_ticks = np.arange(0, 40, 10)
pyplot.plot(x,y, linewidth=2)
pyplot.xticks(x,names,rotation = 90)
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,10))
pyplot.show()
```

and then...the whole body, and i must say something to declare:  I had no background about computer science before, it's really a little bit hard for me to deal with such many datas at the very beginning. Actually i am now doing Internship in a german company and i started to learn python one week ago. I got an assignment from my mentor, I tried to devide the whole assignment into several steps, and I searched the commands of each of the steps and then combine them together with some revising. So, it may seem that I did a lot of useless work. Please be kind in commends(If you have suggestions about that, always glad to hear that of course)

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyplot
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import numpy as np
path = r'C:\Users\AK6PRAKT\Desktop\6daten'
dirs = os.listdir(path) 
s = []
x = []
y = []
names = []
fig = pyplot.figure()
for i in dirs:                             
    if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ".csv": 
        f = open(path+"/"+i)
        iter_f = iter(f);
        str = ""
        for line in iter_f: 
              str = str + line
        s.append(str) 
        with open(path+"/"+i,'r') as r:
            lines=r.readlines()
        with open(path+"/"+i,'w') as w:
            for row in lines:
                if 'Date' not in row:
                    w.write(row)
        columns = defaultdict(list)
        with open(path+"/"+i) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
                    columns[i].append(v)
                    list_temp1 = columns[0]
                    list_temp1 = np.array(list_temp1)
                    list_temp2 = columns[1]
                    list_temp2 = np.array(list_temp2)
            print(list_temp1,list_temp2)
            y.append(float(list_temp2))                                                    
            names.append(list_temp1)
x = range(len(names))
pyplot.ylim((0, 40)) 
my_y_ticks = np.arange(0, 40, 10)
pyplot.plot(x,y, linewidth=2)
pyplot.xticks(x,names,rotation = 90)
pyplot.yticks(my_y_ticks)
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,10))
pyplot.show()
```

[the graphic from parts of datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHq0j.png)
[the graphic can not show while reading all datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT68V.png)

Comment: The error message shows an array with more than one row packed together into one single row. One of your csv files is not formatted correctly.

Comment: @DanielR. OMG, i found that falsh csv file and...it works!!!the graphic shows!!! thank you a lot, Daniel :O

Comment: You're welcome. It's very useful to look at the actual content of the traceback for the errors when doing debugging :)

Comment: @DanielR. got that!